# Do Hibernate session and Entity manager share the same transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

we are currently using Hibernate 3.6 on our application. Application is full of uses of Hibernate Session, Spring HibernateTemplate - recently we started migrating the code to more standard Entity Manager, but it is a gradual process.

So I got into the problem where we use both hibernate session and entity manager in one method (service method which is @Transactional) and one operation depends on the other, like this:

```
hqlQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM address WHERE user_id = 1");
hqlQuery.executeUpdate();

jpaQuery = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 1");
jpaQuery.executeUpdate();
// this throws org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException - cannot delete user because there are still references to this user in address
```

I suspect that this could be because Hibernate uses different transaction (in different connection) for Session and EntityManager - delete of addreses are done in one transaction and delete of user is done in a second transaction - then it's clear why delete of user fails because of foreign key constraint.

Session and EntityManager share the same transaction manager but I have no idea if this is important.

I wanted to test this by getting some transaction ID from session.getTransaction() and em.getTransaction() but there's no identifier.

So the question is - is it possible to share one transaction between Session and EntityManager? If it is, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Hibernate as your JPA provider?  Are all entities mapped in both Hibernate and JPA?

Comment: Yes, Hibernate is used as a JPA provider. All entities are mapped in both JPA and Hibernate. Essentially, we are using JPA EntityManager for the exact thing we used HibernateTemplate/Session.

Comment: You might consider using EntityManager.unrwap(Session.class) to get the Hibernate Session instead of having both a Hibernate SessionFactory and EntityManagerFactory:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 2):

Well, `EntityManager` is a Java Persistence API-related interface, and `Session` (or rather `SessionImpl`) is Hibernate-provided implementation of `EntityManager`.

At runtime `em.createQuery()` returns `javax.persistence.Query` and  `session.createQuery()` returns `org.hibernate.query.Query` which in turn extends `javax.persistence.Query` :)

So eventually under the hood you deal with the same code.

Now, as soon as your code is executed under the same method annotated with `@Transactional` all the operations within that method share one and the same transaction. To make sure you could log transaction begin/end.

To solve your problem I think you need to rewrite your code to use native queries, for as far as I understand `user_id` references table column, not an entity field:

```java
hqlQuery = session.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM address WHERE user_id = 1");
hqlQuery.executeUpdate();

jpaQuery = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 1");
jpaQuery.executeUpdate();
```

However, if you deal with entities and want to keep `*.createQuery()` you need to execute `session.flush()` after `hqlQuery.executeUpdate()`.

It's important to understand, that  without Entities mapped onto both the tables involved `em/Session.createQuery()` wouldn't work out. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40645955/12473843

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but if I remember correctly it is as you have written: the hibernate session and the EntityManager each have a connection to the database - so when your are using both it must be ensured that they share the same transaction.
I would directly get the session from the EntityManager like this:

```
// the old way
Session session = ((HibernateEntityManager)em).getSession();
```

Since Hibernate 5 the `HibernateEntityManager` was deprecated thus you should use the `unwrap` method which is a standard JPA method and thus makes your code more portable between different JPA providers. But I mentioned it in case you are stuck with an older version of hibernate and you can't upgrade...

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);

Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM address WHERE user_id = 1");
hqlQuery.executeUpdate();

Query jpaQuery = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 1");
jpaQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Another possibility could be to finish the first transaction and afterwards do the user delete. But this has several disadvantages like manually managing rollback and the "mixture" between annotation based and manual transaction handling. I haven't tested this and the exception handling is omitted:

```
//Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); // or session.getTransaction()

hqlQuery = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM address WHERE user_id = 1");
hqlQuery.executeUpdate();

session.flush();
tx.commit();
//session.close();

//now do the user deletion
jpaQuery = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = 1");
jpaQuery.executeUpdate();
```