# Cannot delete or update a parent row ConstraintViolationException

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 object entities (User and Phone) and they are supposed to have many-to-many relations.

**User.java**

```
//all columns

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_PHONE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Phone> phones;
```

**Phone.java**

```
//all columns
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_PHONE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<User> userList;
```

Now, I add 2 users with IDs 1 and 2 in my USER table. 
Then, I add a single phone with id 1 and map them to both the user IDs(1&2) .

My USER_PHONE table looks as below:

```
Select * from USER_PHONE;
+----------+---------+
| phone_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        1 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

Now, I wish to remove a user with ID 2. 
When I try to do this, I get an error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`USER_PHONE`, CONSTRAINT `FKC6A847DAFA96A429` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `USER` (`ID`))
```

My delete script:

```
  String query = "DELETE User where id=?1";
        try{
            Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query);
            q.setParameter(1,id);
            q.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " DELETE: userId " + id + " ==> deleted");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

Any idea where am I going wrong ? 
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`. You cannot use `createQuery()` because the table should be present as an entity in your Java code. Also, you need to use the exact SQL format.

`String query = "DELETE FROM USER_PHONE WHERE user_id=?1";`

```
    try{
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
        q.setParameter(1,id);
        q.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " DELETE User_Phone: userId " + id + " ==> deleted");
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }`
```

First delete the row from `USER_PHONE` (using `createNativeQuery()`), and then from `User` (using `createQuery()`)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change.

```
//User class
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
...
private List<Phone> phones;
```

Comment: That, unfortunately does not works. I still get the same error. Any other options?

Comment: can you post the error you got now after this change?

Comment: Error: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`USER_PHONE`, CONSTRAINT `FKC6A847DAFA96A429` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `USER` (`ID`))

Comment: don't use join table in both classes. Say in phone remove that annotation and set mappedBy="phones" in the manytomany annotation. though this does not solve the problem

Comment: one way is to alter your foreign key definition in your sql as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23551881/5039001 . but not the best way to do i think